# Extending DataSourcePublicMetrics to get additional metrics

Tags: spring-boot

We are using a custom DataSource which achieves multi-tenancy. (We have a single DataSource bean which acts like a proxy to other datasources, and the tenant context is set using ThreadLocal variables. My requirement is to get the metrics of the individual datasources proxied by that single DataSource Bean.) Basically, i need to somehow add additional metrics. It seems like the best way would be to extend `DataSourcePublicMetrics`, since `PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration` conditionally creates this bean. The problem is that the fields in `DataSourcePublicMetrics` are all private making reuse difficult. The only solution i see is hide all the internal variables and override the public methods. Is there a better way? I'm using spring-boot 1.2.2.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use composition instead of inheritance.

```
MyCustomMetrics implements PublicMetrics
```

Any bean the implements PublicMetrics is picked up by the actuator to be exposed at /metrics. DataSourcePublicMetrics implements this interface.

You then inject the DataSourcePublicMetrics bean into MyCustomMetrics (this could even be your custom DataSource, but probably better to create a different class). Implement the contract of PublicMetrics.

```
public Collection<Metric<?>> metrics()
```

Just defer it to the DataSourcePublicMetrics implementation, and also add whatever custom metrics you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was trying to get the `DataSourcePublicMetrics` bean to work and that was why i got into the rabbit hole. So, i injected my custom dataSource into the `MyCustomMetrics` bean which implements `PublicMetrics` and got the information from there. I didn't inject `DataSourcePublicMetrics` as it didn't add any value.